# How can I loop through an IP address range?

Tags: network-programming

I want to perform a set of network tasks on an IP address range. As soon as the range is getting bigger than a class c network, I fail to enumerate all hosts in the range.
I want to be able to iterate through all hosts of a network with the netmask `255.255.240.0`.

```
From: 192.168.0.100
To:   192.168.10.100
```

How would one approach this?  It must be a pretty common task. I come from the green fields of Cocoa iPhone programming, so a C-stylish solution would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Am I reading the question wrong? There actually aren't any addresses lying between 192.158.0.255 and 192.168.1.0.  Perhaps you need to edit to make it more clear.

Comment: alxp: you're assuming that the normal IP address map is being used.  At least on my home router, I'm not aware of anything stopping me from running the LAN on 123.234.123.#, despite that being a completely incorrect use of the addressing range available

Comment: thanks. I editet my question. The range was indeed nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulus operator `%`. Here is a primitive example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int counter;
    unsigned int ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 0 };

    for ( counter = 0; counter < 1000; ++counter ) {
        ip[3] = ( ++ ip[3] % 256 );
        if ( !ip[3] ) {
            ip[2] = ( ++ ip[2] % 256 );
        }
        printf("%u:%u:%u:%u\n", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a piece of code that will quickly introduce you to the nuances involved in interpreting the IP Address and iterating through it.

Things get quite simple once you start looking at an IP Address as a 32-bit unsigned integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int iterator;
    int ipStart[]={192,168,0,100};
    int ipEnd[] = {192,168,10,100};

    unsigned int startIP= (
        ipStart[0] << 24 |
        ipStart[1] << 16 |
        ipStart[2] << 8 |
        ipStart[3]);
    unsigned int endIP= (
        ipEnd[0] << 24 |
        ipEnd[1] << 16 |
        ipEnd[2] << 8 |
        ipEnd[3]);

    for (iterator=startIP; iterator < endIP; iterator++)
    {
        printf (" %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
            (iterator & 0xFF000000)>>24,
            (iterator & 0x00FF0000)>>16,
            (iterator & 0x0000FF00)>>8,
            (iterator & 0x000000FF)
        );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just check that none of the elements for `ipStart` and `ipEnd` are greater than 255.
That will not be an IP Address and it will mess up the code too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PHP solution:

```
<?php

$sIP1 = '192.168.0.0';
$sIP2 = '192.168.1.255';

$aIPList = array();
if ((ip2long($sIP1) !== -1) && (ip2long($sIP2) !== -1)) // As of PHP5, -1 => False
 {
 for ($lIP = ip2long($sIP1) ; $lIP <= ip2long($sIP2) ; $lIP++)
  {
  $aIPList[] = long2ip($lIP);
  }
 }
?>
```

There's a good summary of the (basic) maths involved [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ip_routing_on_subnets.html)